# What is the "soft private memory limit" in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-management, python-2.7

A user of my application attempted to send a file as an email attachment using my application. However, doing so raised the following exception which I'm having trouble deciphering

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit with 192.023 MB after servicing 
2762 requests total

While handling this request, the process that handled this request was
found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to
cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application.

If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in 
your application.
```

What is the "soft private memory limit" and what was likely to bring about this exception?

Comment: Looks as if GAE applies a limit to how much memory can be used by the process running the app. Your app exceeded this limit (maybe by trying to hold a very large attachment in a buffer?), so the system took action against it. The only part I find confusing is that the message says the process was "terminated", so in what thread of execution was this exception raised?

Comment: @SteveJessop AFAIK, the process was allowed to finish its last request before being terminated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "soft private memory limit" is the memory limit at which App Engine will stop an instance from receiving any more requests, wait for any outstanding requests, and terminate the instance. Think of it as a graceful shutdown when you're using too much memory.

Hitting the soft limit once in a while is ok since all your requests finish as they should. However, every time this happens, your next request may start up a new instance which may have a latency impact.

Answer (score 20):

I assume you are using the lowest-class frontend or backend instance. (F1 or B1 class) Both have 128 MB memory quota, so your app most likely went over this quota limit. However, this quota appears to be not strictly enforced and Google have some leniency in this (thus the term `soft limit`), I had several F1 app instances consuming ~200MB of memory for minutes before being terminated by the App Engine.

Try increasing your instance class to the next higher-level class (F2 or B2) that have 256MB memory quota and see if the error re-occurs. Also, do some investigation whether the error is reproducible every time you send e-mail with attachments. Because it's possible that what you are seeing is the symptom but not the cause, and the part of your app that consumes lots of memory lies somewhere else.

Comment: I am using the lowest-class instance - that's a good call on increasing the memory limit. I'll try attach something large with a higher instance selected.

Comment: Also don't forget to update backends. It seems to me, AppEngine runs B1 by default. Try: appcfg.py backends . updates (see also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/7U5sVDpjcmk)

Comment: To me it sounds like some memory leak is occurring and the instance at GAE is not releasing memory properly.

Comment: Ibrahim, you said (in a comment to the OP): `AFAIK, the process was allowed to finish its last request before being terminated. – Ibrahim Arief Feb 17 '12 at 23:15` does that mean in this case, the email was probably sent successfully?  Maybe @user714852 could answer?

Comment: @TheRedPea It is probable, yes. This behavior is not documented by Google. (and for a good reason, they may want to change it at any given time) It also depends on how heavy the process is, if it took a long time to finish then GAE might decide to aggressively terminate the instance.