# kmeans clustering with limited memory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am developing an app on App Engine and am using kmeans2 from SciPy.

When the cluster runs, I get this error:

`Exceeded soft private memory limit with 159.852 MB after servicing 1 requests total`

Here is what I'm doing, `color_data` will be around 5 million x,y,z points:

```
def _cluster(color_data, k):
  """ Clusters colors and return top k 

      Arguments:
      ----------
        color_data
          TYPE: list
          DESC: The pixel rgb values to cluster
        k
          TYPE: int
          DESC: number of clusters to find in the colors

      Returns:
      --------
        sorted_colors
          TYPE: list
          DESC: A list of rgb centroids for each color cluster
  """

  # make rgbs into x,y,z points
  x,y,z = [],[],[]
  for color in color_data:
    x.append(color[0])
    y.append(color[1])
    z.append(color[2])

  # averaged_colors are points at center of color clusters
  # labels are cluster numbers for each point
  averaged_colors, labels = kmeans2(array(zip(x,y,z)), k, iter=10)

  # get count of nodes per cluster
  frequencies = {}
  for i in range(k):
    frequencies[i] = labels.tolist().count(i)

  # sort labels on frequency
  sorted_labels = sorted(frequencies.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))

  # sort colors on label they belong to
  sorted_colors = []
  for l in sorted_labels:
    sorted_colors.append(tuple(averaged_colors[l[0]].tolist()))

  return sorted_colors
```

How can I do this in under 128MB of memory?

EDIT:
On my local machine, running my app shows ~500 MB of memory being used in my Activity Monitor

Comment: I believe Mini-Batch K-means implementation in sklearn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html is more efficient in time and space; however, it is less accurate.

Comment: You need to get below 128MB, F1 instances will let you peak for short periods but not for long and will still run into problems.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

Comment: MiniBatchKMeans only saves me 20 MB, which leaves me at ~480 MB on my local machine.  Still way to much

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use all pixels.**

K-Means will usually return an almost identical result if you only use 10% or less of the pixels. Because it computes means, and the mean doesn't change much anymore, if you add more information, unless the data is distributed differently.

Only using 10% of the pixels should make your application use much less memory.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on which 10% to use?  A random sample? Every 10th pixel?

Comment: A true random sample would obviously be better, but random number generation may be too slow for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't decrease the sustained memory usage of your operations, [you should look for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331592/what-is-the-soft-private-memory-limit-in-gae) for advice on increasing your memory allotment inside apps or change to another provider. For $20/ month this is a simple request of a rackspace server, although by definition it's closer to the metal and requires more setup.