# Avoiding 'Exceeded soft private memory limit' while receiving email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, email-attachments

**What I have:**

I have configured GAE so that it will receive email, delete attachments from it and store it in the blobstore, and then send the mail.

**Problem statement:**

When GAE is receiving any mail from gmail having attachment size greater than 5 MB , it is throwing 'Exceeded soft memory limit' error (I guess GAE can receive email with attachments upto 10 MB).

**What I know**

According to the link [What is the "soft private memory limit" in GAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331592/what-is-the-soft-private-memory-limit-in-gae) i need to increase my frontend and backend instance class so that memory quota can be increased.

**What I need**

I need to know if there is any thing that I may be missing or any idea to work with emails having attachments upto 10MB. All I need to do is detach attachments from email and store in blobstore and then send the email with blob keys generated with the same. Above workflow is working fine till 5MB attachment but is failing for large attachments with size upto 10MB.

Any help will be appreciated. Do let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks!